# Find values in a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$-2, x, y, 1024 $

find the value of $x$ and $y$
what i got so far is that
$x/-2 = y/x = 1024/y $ 
and thats for finding the common ratio, cross multiply and isolating x and y gave me
$x^2 = -2y$
$y^2 = 1024x$
then I got nowhere after this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply all the terms in these two equalities we get
$$\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)^3=-\frac{x^3}8=-512$$
so $x=16$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: sorry that I'm not getting this. Explain a little more, where did the cube come from?

Comment: $$\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)^3=-\frac{x}{2}\times\frac yx\times\frac{1024}y$$

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try also in a very basic manner $$a_1=-2$$ $$a_2=r \times a_1=x$$ $$a_3=r \times a_2=r^2 \times a_1=y$$ $$a_4=r \times a_3=r^2 \times a_2=r^3 \times a_1=1024$$ Using the first and last equations, you then have $$\frac{a_4}{a_1}=r^3=-\frac{1024}{2}=-512$$ So,    $r=-8$. So going backwards, $x=-2 \times (-8)=16$, $y=16 \times (-8)=-128$